# Beginner Assignment need help! Scan files -> Data Validation -> Printwriter

Tags: java, loops, io

I am really stuck on the assignment of Java. Just a beginner and I need to write a donation management system that needs to read 2 files (donator records & instructions) which I need to read and validate the donator records, then print writes the validated records and print it in certain toString format.

Need to read records like these:(fields may in any order)

```
phone 02111111
name Posephine Bloggs
birthday 01-06-1980
address 1 Grace Street, Lane Cove, NSW
postcode 2066
recipient dog care, the disabled
donation 100, 300

address 102 Smith St, Summer hill, NSW
postcode 2130
name Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs
birthday 13-05-1960
phone 11222009
recipient animal protection, lifecare
donation 50, 200
```

I have created 3 Scanner already,
1. Scan the record file
2. Scan through every lines
3. Scan the keywords and values

But then I got the result file with every field created an donator object instead of putting all the fields in an single object.

Output like this:

```
name: null
birthday: null
address: null
postcode: 0
phone: null

name:  Posephine Bloggs
birthday: null
address: null
postcode: 0
phone: null

name: null
birthday: 01-06-1980
address: null
postcode: 0
phone: null

name: null
birthday: null
address:  1 Grace Street, Lane Cove, NSW
postcode: 0
phone: null

name: null
birthday: null
address: null
postcode: 0
phone: null
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the question ?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
while(scanRecord.hasNextLine()) {
    donator a = new donator();

    String line = scanRecord.nextLine();
```

This means that you will have a new donator created for each line you read, whereas you *should* create a new donator whenever you read a *blank* line.

One way to fix this is to move the declaration of `a` out of the while loop, and only initialise `a` if the line read is blank. You should also add the donator to the list in the else branch instead.

```
donator a = new donator();
while(scanRecord.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanRecord.nextLine();
    if (!line.isBlank()) {
        ...
    } else {
        donatorList.addDonator(a);
        a = new donator();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I need to delete the code as my university has a system to scan through my assignment coding, if its coming from the internet i will fail this. Im sorry :(